# What do we call a function that converges with composition over greater than $\omega$ times?

Tags: convergence-divergence, induction, ordinals, transfinite-induction

Let $S_n$ be an ordered set of numbers indexed by a countable ordinal $n\in\omega^\omega$ such as:

$\ldots 7,49,343,\ldots5,25,125,\ldots,3,9,27,\ldots,2,4,8,\ldots$

Then let this be a topological space such that every subsequence of the form $p_n,p_n^2,p_n^3,\ldots$ converges to $p_{n-1}$ or to $1$ in the case of $2^\infty$

Let some function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ send each number to its successor: $f(s_n)=s_{n+1}$ e.g. $2\mapsto4$.

What topological or sequential term describes the property of this function $f$ that it is directed towards $2^\omega$?  Is this what transfinite induction refers to?

I can't say $f$ converges to $\langle2\rangle$ but how do I say it converges to $\langle2\rangle$ on transfinite induction (or whatever the correct term is)?  I'm aware I can simply say something like the orbit of $f$ is directed.  Maybe that's the only answer.

I'm aware I can say let $\overline f=\lim_{m\to\infty}f^m(x)$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \overline f^{\text { }n}(x)=1$

---

In its most general form: What is the term for a function which converges not only when composed infinitely many times, but when one takes it to a limit and then composes infinitely many times again, possibly through infinitely many limit points, it eventually stabilises.

Comment: Could you write a more-or-less general mathematical statement at the end to clarify what you mean? Or this is a really specific example that you found somewhere else? In this case, could you write what you look for in your original problem?

Comment: @AndreaMarino I've added a wording to the end in the most general form I can.

Comment: So you want to know the name of the following property. Given $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and an injection $\phi: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$, you have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} f \phi(n,m) =L$ , no matter which $\phi$ we choose. Is this correct? Note that this models the idea of "taking limit points" (in m) and then taking the limit of the results (in n).

Comment: @AndreaMarino yes, that looks right. Composition over $\omega^{\omega}$ copies of $f$ converges to $L$.  Except maybe we need $\phi:\Bbb N^\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$?  The example I give using prime powers does explain it.

Comment: Let's call this "square limit" of f. If f admits an ordinary limit, then the square limit exist and coincide. On the other side, suppose that there exist sequences $s(n) ,t(n)$ such that $lim f(s_n) = a, lim f(t_n) =b$, $a<b$. These are the sequences that realize liminf and limsup. Take an arbitrary injection $\phi: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ and define $\psi :\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ in the following way $\psi(n,m) =s( \phi(n,m))$ if n is odd, and $t(\phi(n,m))$ if n is even. The resulting limit of limit points is the alternating seq a,b, that does not converge.

Comment: So the square limit exist iff the ordinary limit exist and in that case they coincide.

Comment: @AndreaMarino are you assuming standard topology on $\Bbb N$ or is this more general?  As the application is the function $f(x)=x+\frac{21}{64}\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$

Comment: What topology are you using to define "limit points"?

Comment: @AndreaMarino I was considering any arbitrary countable set in any arbitrary topology

Comment: The proof goes in the same way for arbitrary topologies. If the sequence does not converge itself to a number, then there exist an open $U$ such that the sequence is infinitely many times outside and inside $U$. Repeat the proof using the two subsequences inside and outside U. I don't think this is a complete proof but should give the idea :)

Comment: @AndreaMarino thanks, this could be really helpful.

Comment: @AndreaMarino I struggle to follow your description, although with more work maybe I will get it.  Does what you wrote apply here, which is the application?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420468/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful phrase to google is [transfinite superpositions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transfinite+superpositions%22&filter=0), although I think at the present time “transfinite composition” would be a better phrase to use if you intend to write about this.

[Nina Karlovna Bary [Bari] (1901-1961)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nina_Bari) was probably the first person to introduce the idea of transfinite iterations (compositions) of a function, this being in the following two papers.

**[1]** [*Mémoire sur la représentation finie des fonctions continues. Première Partie: Les superpositions de fonctions absolument continues*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01455694), **Mathematische Annalen** 103 (1930), 185-248.

**[2]** [*Mémoire sur la représentation finie des fonctions continues. Deuxième Partie: Le théorème fondamental sur la représentation finie*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01455713), **Mathematische Annalen** 103 (1930), 598-653.

Besides the following 2 papers and 1 conference talk by [John Todd (1911-2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_(Jack)_Todd), I don’t know to what extent Bary or others followed up with this work:

**[3]** [*Superpositions of functions (I): Transfinite superpositions of absolutely continuous functions*](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-10.2.166), **Journal of the London Mathematical Society** (1) 10 #3 (July 1935), 166-171.

**[4]** [*Superpositions of functions (II): Transfinite superpositions of absolutely continuous functions*](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-41.6.433), **Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society** (2) 41 (1936), 433-439.

**[5]** [*Transfinite superpositions of absolutely continuous functions*](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1936.2/ICM1936.2.ocr.pdf), pp. 110-111 in **Comptes Rendus du Congrès International des Mathématiciens** (Oslo, 1936), 1937, xvi + 289 pages.

Regarding transfinite sequences of functions in general, there have probably been over 100 papers dealing with this topic, mostly published in the last 4 or 5 decades. See this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transfinite+sequence%22+%22functions%22+%22convergence%22&filter=0) and this [google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22transfinite+sequence%22+%22functions%22+%22convergence%22).

Comment: What I can see of these articles is quite heavy going, and they're behind a paywall.  FWIW, this is the application: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420468/